# Error for SVM tuning in R for Kaggle Titanic dataset

Tags: r, svm, kaggle

I'm trying to complete tuning for an SVM model in R, using the Titanic Kaggle dataset.

When I run the following code:

```
tune.out = tune(svm, Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + Fare + Embarked + family, 
            data = boat, kernel = "linear", 
            ranges = list(cost = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100)))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in names(ret2) <- rowns : 
 'names' attribute [90] must be the same length as the vector [71]
```

With the traceback:

```
3: predict.svm(model, if (!is.null(validation.x)) validation.x else if (useFormula) data[-train.ind[[sample]], 
   , drop = FALSE] else if (inherits(train.x, "matrix.csr")) train.x[-train.ind[[sample]], 
   ] else train.x[-train.ind[[sample]], , drop = FALSE])
2: predict.func(model, if (!is.null(validation.x)) validation.x else if (useFormula) data[-train.ind[[sample]], 
   , drop = FALSE] else if (inherits(train.x, "matrix.csr")) train.x[-train.ind[[sample]], 
   ] else train.x[-train.ind[[sample]], , drop = FALSE])
1: tune(svm, Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + Fare + Embarked + family, 
   data = boat, kernel = "linear", ranges = list(cost = c(0.001, 
       0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100)))
```

I understand that something might be wrong with my variables -- any thought of what that might be?

If it helps, I haven't modified any of the variables but have dropped a bunch (those not seen in the tuning formula and created a new variable `family` by:

```
boat$family = boat$SibSp + boat$Parch
boat$family[boat$family > 0] = 1
```

Boat is a `data.table`.

Comment: _"the Titanic Kaggle dataset"_ - what's that?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data?train.csv

Comment: Read what I wrote above -- I created that variable.

Comment: I can reproduce the error, however, I cannot see where it comes from (`debug(predict.func)`) - besides that the `NA`s in `boat$Age` are responsible. However, I guess using `na.omit(boat)` or guessing using e.g. `missForrest` is not an option...

Comment: ^ That was it. Thanks